# `git checkout` not resetting file

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

Here's my situation. I'm on branch `my_branch`, have accidentally modified a file (and have staged these changes), and would like to reset this file to how it was on `master`. However, if I doing so using `git checkout`, I get an error (see below for details).

```
$ git branch
* my_branch
  master

$ git fetch origin master
From [MY REMOTE]
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD

$ git status
modified:   my_folder/my_file.py

$ git checkout origin/master -- my_folder/my_file.py
error: pathspec 'my_folder/my_file.py' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

How should I be using `git checkout`? What might be causing git to list this file as 'modified' in `git status`, but to say it's not recognised during `git checkout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've modified the file locally and staged it you need to do `git restore --staged my_folder/my_file.py` to unstage that file.

After the file is no longer staged you can do `git restore my_folder/my_file.py` to discard all changes.

Comment: I tried that and got `git: 'restore' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Comment: What version of git are you running?

Comment: `git restore` was added in 2.23.0, make sure you have at least that version installed.

Comment: 2.17.1. OK, I'll try updating

Comment: You can do `git reset HEAD -- my_folder/my_file.py` as an alternative. After it's unstaged just do `git checkout -- my_folder/my_file.py` to discard changes